# jquery waypoints won't fire if I use overflow:hidden

Tags: jquery, overflow, jquery-waypoints

I have a page laid out in full-window divs. Navigation is accomplished by hitting nav buttons, and I don't want users to be able to scroll to a spot between divs, so I set overflow:hidden on my container. That part works fine.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="slide" id="slide1"> <span class="content">page 1</span>

        </div>
        <div class="slide" id="slide2"> <span class="content">page 2</span>

        </div>
        <div class="slide" id="slide3"> <span class="content">page 3</span>

        </div>
    </div>
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#slide1" class="navbtn1" class="scroll">&nbsp;</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#slide2" class="navbtn2" class="scroll">&nbsp;</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#slide3" class="navbtn3" class="scroll">&nbsp;</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

And here's the javascript I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Make navbtn active when page is scrolled down to slide
$('#slide1').waypoint(function(down){
  $('#main .active').removeClass('active'); // remove the class from the currently selected
  $('#main a.navbtn1').addClass('active'); // add the class to the newly clicked link
});

$('#slide2').waypoint(function(down){
  $('#main .active').removeClass('active'); // remove the class from the currently selected
  $('#main a.navbtn2').addClass('active'); // add the class to the newly clicked link
});

$('#slide3').waypoint(function(down){
  $('#main .active').removeClass('active'); // remove the class from the currently selected
  $('#main a.navbtn3').addClass('active'); // add the class to the newly clicked link
}); 
});
```

I do have a block of code for firing when I'm scrolling up, but it looks just like this but with 'up' instead of 'down' and an offset: -1.

The problem is, I'm using the Waypoints jQuery plugin to detect when a #slide is at the top of the viewport and set the active state on the associated navbtn. And Waypoints is not firing any more. If I turn remove the overflow:hidden, it works, but with that in there, it only fires once, when I load the page.

Any idea why Waypoints would stop firing when I use overflow:hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply the overflow:hidden only on body element and not on html and body elements.
Worked for me